# After the American Civil War, which states had the most problems with rejoining the Union?

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, american-civil-war

Once the American Civil war ended, did some states encounter more difficulty than others when it came to rejoining the Union? What circumstances or conditions might have contributed to their issues?

Comment: How does one measure resistance? Does a fierce Confederate militia being active in non-seceding Indiana outweigh the anti-secessionist sentiment in western Virginia? Do virulent anti-conscription riots in the north count as anti-Union actions?

Comment: @mdnth Did you mean "after" the Civil War?

Comment: I have modified the question to make it more sensible. I hope this will help to get some of the negative votes reversed. Let me know if this does not reflect your intentions.

Comment: This is way different from what it kind of looked like he was trying to ask, but now its a good enough question that I'm retracting my votes (and prior comments).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question refers to "problems" without defining them, so I am going to cast my answer in terms of which states rejoined the Union earlier (supposedly fewer "problems") rather than later. I will try to tie the rejoining order to the best correlation I can find.

According to the link below, Tennessee, Arkansas, North Carolina, and Florida were the first four Confederate states to rejoin the Union. They were [Upper South](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_South) (or in the case of Florida, peripheral) states that were not part of the mainstream South. The first three states plus Virginia did not join the Confederacy until after the firing on Fort Sumter.

http://wiki.answers.com/Q/When_did_the_Confederate_states_rejoin_the_Union

The last seven states to rejoin were Louisiana, South Carolina, Alabama, Georgia, Virginia, Mississpi, and Texas. With the notable exception of Virginia, these were the hard core "deep South" states. The most pro-Union part of Virginia was West Virginia, which "seceded from secession," meaning that what was left was more pro South than the other Upper South states.

Comment: Answers.com hardly constitutes a reliable source.

Comment: Usually your answers are very thorough, I don't see how this answers the question about the difficulties the states might have had in rejoining during unification.  I also wouldn't consider North Carolina a border or peripheral state...

Comment: I took that part to mean "outside the Deep South" (which is quite true for North Carolina). Changing "border" to "upper south" to make this clearer. I'd suggest Tom read over the wikipedia Deep South page ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_South ), clean up the terminology a bit, and IMHO most of these complaints would be moot.

Comment: @Luke:I'm satisfied with their FACTUAL content (the dates and order of the states rejoining the Union). The interpretations are mine.